# Magento 2 - how can I add 2 dropdowns in the same row?like the picture below

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, dropdown-attribute, multiselect-attribute, dynamic-rows

[image]

how can i add 2 dropdowns in the same row,how can i add 2 dropdown like the image above

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find out any solutions, you can use htmlContent of the UI component, then custom all dynamic rows on phtml file. Or, you can create a block with your custom template if you use the block to generate Admin form.

I've tried it and was successful, but I can't share it because of some reason. Sorry about that!
[image]